# Salary column is not getting updated in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want the user when click on Edit should be able to edit the salary cloumn. The scenario is like, If User doesn't put any value in salary textbox, it should show "00000" and also should go into the table. And if the user put any value on edit of it, like he puts 65000, it should also get updated.

Here, Only the static data is going like 00000 only. But at run time this column is not getting updated.

Note: Onclick on View, the page redirects me to the other page where user puts the data.

```
 protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        string salary = "00000";
        if (hdnjobId.Value == "0")
        {
            Job newjob = new Job();
            newjob.JobCode = GenerateJobCode();

            newjob.EmpName = txtPostedByName.Text.Trim();
            newjob.EmpCode = txtPostedByEmpCode.Text.Trim();
            newjob.EmailId1 = txtEmailId1.Text;
            newjob.EmailId2 = txtEmailId2.Text;

            newjob.Position = txtPosition.Text;
            newjob.Location = ddlLocation.SelectedValue;
            newjob.BusinessUnit = ddlBusinessUnit.SelectedValue;
            newjob.EduReq = txtEduReq.Text;
            newjob.MinExp = txtMinExp.Text;
            newjob.MinExpYrs = ddlMinExpYr.SelectedValue;
            newjob.MaxExp = txtMaxExp.Text;
            newjob.MaxExpYrs = ddlMaxExpYr.SelectedValue;
            if (txtSalaryRange2.Enabled == true)
            {
                newjob.SalaryRange = salary;
                txtSalaryRange.Enabled = false;
            }
            newjob.SalaryRange = txtSalaryRange.Text;
            newjob.Description = txtJobDesc.Text;
            newjob.Skills = txtSkills.Text;
            newjob.DateOfPosting = Convert.ToDateTime(txtJobPostingDate.Text);
            newjob.DateOfClosing = Convert.ToDateTime(txtJobClosingDate.Text);
            newjob.Status = chkStatus.Checked;
            _helper.Save(newjob);
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "added", "alert('Job added successfully'); location.href = 'CareerJobList.aspx';", true);
        }
        else
        {
            var newjob = _helper.GetJob(Convert.ToInt32(hdnjobId.Value));
            newjob.JobCode = lblJobCode.Text;

            newjob.EmpName = txtPostedByName.Text.Trim();
            newjob.EmpCode = txtPostedByEmpCode.Text.Trim();
            newjob.EmailId1 = txtEmailId1.Text;
            newjob.EmailId2 = txtEmailId2.Text;

            newjob.Position = txtPosition.Text;
            newjob.Location = ddlLocation.SelectedValue;
            newjob.BusinessUnit = ddlBusinessUnit.SelectedValue;
            newjob.EduReq = txtEduReq.Text;
            newjob.MinExp = txtMinExp.Text;
            newjob.MinExpYrs = ddlMinExpYr.SelectedValue;
            newjob.MaxExp = txtMaxExp.Text;
            newjob.MaxExpYrs = ddlMaxExpYr.SelectedValue;
            if (txtSalaryRange2.Enabled == true)
            {
               // newjob.SalaryRange = salary;
                txtSalaryRange.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                txtSalaryRange2.Enabled = false;
                newjob.SalaryRange = txtSalaryRange.Text;
            }
            //newjob.SalaryRange = txtSalaryRange.Text;
            newjob.Description = txtJobDesc.Text;
            newjob.Skills = txtSkills.Text;
            newjob.DateOfPosting = Convert.ToDateTime(txtJobPostingDate.Text);
            newjob.DateOfClosing = Convert.ToDateTime(txtJobClosingDate.Text);
            newjob.Status = chkStatus.Checked;
            _helper.Save(newjob);
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "added", "alert('Job updated successfully');location.href='CareerJobList.aspx';", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Also see the aspx code:-

```
<tr>
                <td class="td">Salary</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="txtfld-popup" ID="txtSalaryRange" runat="server" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox><span style="color: #CF060D;">lakhs per annum</span>
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="txtfld-popup" ID="txtSalaryRange2" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox><span style="color: #CF060D;"></span>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="error_msg" ID="reqSalaryRange" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtSalaryRange" ErrorMessage="Please enter salary" SetFocusOnError="true"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                  <%--  <span style="color: #f00;">lakhs per annum</span>--%>
                     <asp:RegularExpressionValidator  CssClass="error_msg" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"  ControlToValidate="txtSalaryRange" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Salary" ValidationExpression="^[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|0+\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbButtonYes" runat="server" Text="Show" GroupName="salary" AutoPostBack="true"  OnCheckedChanged="rbButtonYes_CheckedChanged"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbButtonNo" runat="server" Text="Not Show" GroupName="salary" OnCheckedChanged="rbButtonNo_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Please help, how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply check :

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSalaryRange.Text))
{
   newjob.SalaryRange = txtSalaryRange.Text;
}
else
{
   newjob.SalaryRange = "00000";
}
```

An you code is duplicated, you should re-factor your code to move the if-else code to a separate function.

Comment: Rabi, it is working exact. But one thing. when I add nothing. the table should get a string value of "00000". how to achieve that

Comment: are you still using - if (txtSalaryRange2.Enabled == true) ? I don't see the use of this line .just remove your txtSalaryRange2.Enabled check and use the above code instead. Let me know how it works.

Comment: I am not using that line, But If I use radiobutton checked to NO, it still displays me the entered value. It should not show the value

Comment: you have few options -  1. you can set the value of txtSalaryRange.Text to empty when rbButtonNo_CheckedChanged is fired, if you don't want to preserve the input value . 2. If you want to keep the input value (which is unlikely in your case), save the value inside a hidden field  when rbButtonNo_CheckedChanged is fired. And when rbButtonYes_CheckedChanged is fired, just restore the value back to txtSalaryRange. 3. if you are using jQuery / javascript, you can quickly do that in client side, you won't need any server side processing.

Comment: Rabi, can u please let me know how to achieve this in Jquery. ?

Comment: you should probably add it as a new question. If my suggestion helped you please marked it as answered and post a new question specific to jQuery .